# Ошибка: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
HOST = 'https://www.drom.ru/'
URL = 'https://auto.drom.ru/'
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0'
}
FILE = 'cars.csv'
def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a', class_='css-1ctbluq ewrty961')
    cars = []
    for item in items:
        cars.append(
            {
                'cars_name': item.find('div', class_='css-17lk78h e3f4v4l2').get_text(strip=True),
                'cars_price': item.find('span', class_='css-byj1dh e162wx9x0').get_text(strip=True),
                'cars_link': item.find('a', class_='css-1ctbluq ewrty961').get('href')
            }
        )
    print(cars)

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Сайт недоступен!')

parse()
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "E:\Python s\Парсинг Дрома\Drom's Parsing.py", line 36, in <module>
    parse()
  File "E:\Python s\Парсинг Дрома\Drom's Parsing.py", line 32, in parse
    get_content(html.text)
  File "E:\Python s\Парсинг Дрома\Drom's Parsing.py", line 24, in get_content
    'cars_link': item.find('a', class_='css-1ctbluq ewrty961').get('href')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Я понимаю что, ошибка возникает из-за того, что я пытаюсь найти class_='css-1ctbluq ewrty961' в нём же. Но не понимаю как её решить, ссылка на автомобиль находится только в этом классе. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: the_sterres, вам предоставили два ответа. Выберите один ответ, который помог решить вашу проблему и отметьте его как правильный. Если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда не делайте так

```py
item.find('div', class_='css-17lk78h e3f4v4l2').get_text(strip=True)
```

> Ошибка возникает в случае если `item.find('div', class_='css-17lk78h e3f4v4l2') is None`

Лучше делать так

```py
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a', class_='css-1ctbluq ewrty961')
    cars = []
    for item in items:
        cars.append(
            {
                'cars_name': a.get_text(strip=True) if (
                    a := item.find('div', class_='css-17lk78h e3f4v4l2')
                ) else None,

                'cars_price': span.get_text(strip=True) if (
                    span := item.find('span', class_='css-byj1dh e162wx9x0')
                ) else None,

                'cars_link': a.get('href') if (
                    a := item.find('a', class_='css-1ctbluq ewrty961')
                ) else None
            }
        )
    print(cars)
```

> Такой подход даст вам возможность избежать исключение в случае если первый элемент не будет найден

*Описаный вариант будет работать для python3.8+*

Comment: Спасибо! Обязательно учту.